# The variable inside while loop is not remembered. Mysql bash script auto_increment

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, while-loop, auto-increment

I've working on this script for quite some time. But I started to see some errors when I tried to add a variable ($EMAIL_MSG) to store some strings of text to later be emailed. It seems that the variable inside while loop is not remembered. ([A variable modified inside a while loop is not remembered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280/modifying-variable-inside-while-loop-is-not-remembered))

Here is part of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# This is bash script checks when auto_increment column is reaching its limit
# To run Script $ ./auto_increment_check.sh [username] [password]

MYSQL_USER="$1"
MYSQL_PASSWD="$2"
MYSQLCONNECT="mysql -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWD"
MAX_RATIO="0.8" # Max percentage of fullness of an auto_increment column   (ex. '0.8' means 80% full)
EMAIL_MSG=""
EMAIL_RCPNT="user@company.com"

QUERY="
SELECT table_schema,
       table_name,
       data_type,
       ( CASE data_type
           WHEN 'tinyint' THEN 255
           WHEN 'smallint' THEN 65535
           WHEN 'mediumint' THEN 16777215
           WHEN 'int' THEN 4294967295
           WHEN 'bigint' THEN 18446744073709551615
         end >> IF(Locate('unsigned', column_type) > 0, 0, 1) ) AS max_value
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_schema NOT IN ( 'mysql', 'information_schema', 'performance_schema')
       AND data_type IN ('tinyint','smallint','mediumint','int','bigint')
       AND extra = 'auto_increment'"

$MYSQLCONNECT --batch -N -e "$QUERY" | while read DATABASE TABLE DATA_TYPE MAX_VALUE;

do
  NEXT_AUTO_INCREMENT=`$MYSQLCONNECT --batch -N -e "show create table $DATABASE.$TABLE" |  awk -F'AUTO_INCREMENT=' 'NF==1{print "0";next}{sub(/ .*/,"",$2);print $2}'`
  AUTO_INCREMENT_RATIO=$(awk 'BEGIN {printf "%3.2f\n", '$NEXT_AUTO_INCREMENT' / '$MAX_VALUE'}')

  if [[ $(awk 'BEGIN{print ('$AUTO_INCREMENT_RATIO'>='$MAX_RATIO')}') -eq 1 ]] ; then
    EMAIL_MSG="$EMAIL_MSG\n\nAuto Increment Warning on $(hostname) - $DATABASE.$TABLE - NEXT AUTO INCREMENT: $NEXT_AUTO_INCREMENT, MAX CAPACITY: $MAX_VALUE, RATIO: $AUTO_INCREMENT_RATIO."
  fi

done

if [ EMAIL_MSG != "" ]; then
    echo -e $EMAIL_MSG | mail -s "Auto Increment Warning on $(hostname) " $EMAIL_RCPNT
fi
```

The problem seems to be that the while loop is executed in a subshell. So any changes I do for the variable $EMAIL_MSG will not be available once the subshell exits.

I read that I should modify the while loop like this:

```
while read DATABASE TABLE DATA_TYPE MAX_VALUE;
do
  ...
  ...
  ...
done <<< '$MYSQLCONNECT --batch -N -e "$QUERY"'

if [ EMAIL_MSG != "" ]; then
    echo -e $EMAIL_MSG | mail -s "Auto Increment Warning on $(hostname) " $EMAIL_RCPNT
fi
```

But I'm getting errors:

```
[root@localhost /]# ./vagrant/auto.sh root root
Mon Jan 27 21:04:01 UTC 2014: Auto Increment Check starting.
./vagrant/auto.sh: line 53: syntax error near unexpected token `--batch'
./vagrant/auto.sh: line 53: `done <<< $MYSQLCONNECT --batch -N -e "$QUERY"'
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @Bill Karwin Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
done < <($MYSQLCONNECT --batch -N -e "$QUERY")
```

The construct `<(...)` is called process substitution.  It runs the command inside parentheses and makes it output available as if a FIFO had been created.  The construct `< <(...)` connects the output of the FIFO to stdin on your while loop.

Process substitution requires both `bash` and an operating system, such as linux, that supports FIFOs.  A mere bourne shell will not support it.

**Alternatively**, this could be done as a here string:

```
done <<<"$($MYSQLCONNECT --batch -N -e "$QUERY")"
```

This uses command substitution (`$(...)`) to capture the output of the `$MYSQLCONNECT` command and then uses a here-string (`<<<`) to provide that as stdin to your `while read` loop.  Note the double-quotes outside the command substitution.  They are necessary to preserve the newlines within the command output.  Without those double-quotes, the output of `$MYSQLCONNECT` would appear to the `while read` loop as a single long line.

If single-quotes were used instead of double quotes, as in:

```
done <<<'$($MYSQLCONNECT --batch -N -e "$QUERY")' # Don't use this
```

then no command would be executed and the literal string `$($MYSQLCONNECT --batch -N -e "$QUERY")` would be provided to the `while read` loop.

Comment: While `<(...)` will work, `Here Strings` denoted by `<<<` will also work. This is especially useful for short strings. The error in the OP's post is the failure to write the statement as a process substitution and instead wrote it as a literal string.

Answer (score 0):

The following won't do what you think:

```
if [ EMAIL_MSG != "" ]; then
```

because it doesn't expand the variable $EMAIL_MSG, it just uses the literal string "EMAIL_MSG".

Use this:

```
if [ ! -z "$EMAIL_MSG" ]; then
```

There are other problems I can see in your script.

- The issue of using `<<<` is immaterial. Go back to running a command and piping in to `while` like your original script.
- Don't use single-quotes if you want to expand shell variables inside the string.
- Your passwords will fail if they contain spaces, or semicolon, or ampersand, or hash, or several other special characters.

  Actually, I wouldn't use the `-u` and `-p` options at all. Put the username and password into a config file and then pass `--defaults-extra-file` to load that config file. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html

There might be more problems -- that's just what I noticed.